# Did India conduct a fake military strike across the Western border in 2016?

Tags: politics, war, military, india, pakistan

[On 29 September 2016](https://www.ndtv.com/india-news/surgical-strikes-across-line-of-control-loc-at-7-terror-camps-in-pok-1467925) Indian government claimed that they conducted a 'Surgical Strike' (military operation) across the Western border with Pakistan.

- [Pakistan military rejected the claim instantaneously](https://timesofislamabad.com/01-Oct-2016/fake-surgical-strike-dg-ispr-briefing-to-national-and-international-media-at-loc).
- [UN observers rejected the claim](http://indianexpress.com/article/india/india-news-india/india-snubs-un-for-saying-didnt-observe-loc-firing-3060608/).
- [There were inconsistencies in the narrative from various Indian state institutions](https://www.firstpost.com/india/indian-armys-surgical-strikes-how-modi-government-began-well-and-then-lost-the-plot-3037282.html).
- Some international media (*[BBC](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-india-37702790)*, *[The Diplomat](https://thediplomat.com/2016/09/is-india-capable-of-a-surgical-strike-in-pakistan-controlled-kashmir/)*) threw [doubts](https://tribune.com.pk/story/1193058/uri-aftermath-global-media-doubts-surgical-strike-claims/) against the claim.
- Former BSF soldier [Tej Bahadur Yadav](https://www.thequint.com/news/india/tej-bahadur-yadav-bsf-jawan-protest) who was dismissed from BSF for [exposing BSF's corruption](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ooNPeX3H7lM) on the Facebook [rejected the government's claim](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k0Wb25AfsH8) as he was stationed in that location during the incident.

**Did India conduct a fake '*Surgical Strike*' across the Western border?**

Comment: Hi. We are a website, we do not have direct access to Indian military records or intelligence. You have quoted several credible and informed sources doubting the claim, and that is probably the best information you are going to get.